# Automatically generate WCF service, by reflection.

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, reflection, attributes

We are currently writing a back-end system, and plan on providing a layer of methods through WCF. Is there any tool out there, or open source library that through reflection by reading attributes, for instance [WCFEnabled], would make the methods available through a particular WCF Channel available?

For instance, imagine a WCF service, ItemService. In the Item class, there would be a method named "AddItem". On adding [WCFEnabled], that method would be available on compilation through the ItemService.

Answer (score 2):

Erm. `[OperationContract]` ?

However, not sure if these will work on a class methods, normally they're put on interface methods and your class implements the interface.

Comment: The OperationContract attribute will work on class methods just the same.

Comment: That is how you normally code WCF. You write an interface, and assign on top of the signatures the methods which will be available for the outside world.

However, what I would like, is when designing entities in your class library, you would define which methods you would like to be accessible through WCF.

Then, a separate project would dynamically go through the entities, see which are to be exposed, and automatically create a WCF endpoint. So, you would not have to code any WCF code, but just assign methods to be exposed in a channel.

Answer (score 0):

We have done something similar by using T4 templates to build the service interfaces, implementations and client proxies.

The T4 template parses a Service Project and extracts all methods that are decorated with a custom attribute. Then it builds svc files with an implemenation class/interface for each service it discovers. It also creates the client proxies.

Comment: Thanks Wouter de Kort, from what I read it looks like this is the way to move forward. Did you follow any examples found, which is similar to our scenario?

I am looking at https://github.com/davidalpert/TestableWCFSample

Comment: @StephenBorg I didn't follow any particle example. The steps I took where to first write the proxy code by hand (without all the bagege that an Add Service Reference adds) and then created T4 templates for the service interface, the svc file and the service implementation. The whole proxy is just a WCF wrapper that calls the real service code so it's easy to implement.